# How to phrase an acceptable question asking for software and hardware?

Tags: discussion

I am "asking for a friend". I think that the software choice will drive the hardware choice, but nevertheless I am asking for both  software and hardware. Is that on topic, or can I make it so?

Basically, what is being sought is a fitness tracker that does not share user data with "Big Brother & the Holding Company" (AKA, Apple, Google, et al).

The requested software should communicate directly with the tracker device, without passing through any server.

That's the major point. Choice of hardware would be from a list compatible with the recommended software (for Android and/or Windows). The more features the better, but privacy is non-negotiable.

How best to ask ?

Comment: The answer would be "any device that works with [Gadgetbridge](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge)," if the "other device" runs Android. And if you check the list of supported devices on linked page, there are quite a few. But with the question basically being for a device and not the software (it would match [Tims answer here](/a/113/185)), I'm not sure how to make it on-topic. However, why not try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which is in open beta currently?

Comment: Thanks, Izzy. GadgetBridge sounds like the answer.  I didd think about h/w recs, but it's _almost_ the same dilemma - asking for a s/w h/w pair

Comment: One could say: But a better match as you are looking for the hardware primarily. One doesn't write software in the hope other folks will build matching hardware for it. But the other way around is more likely.

Comment: While I agree about building the h/w first, I disagree that my question is primarily about h/w. I will accept any h/w, so long as it is compatible with some s/w having a specific feature.  What do you think? Can I ask, and, if so, where?

Comment: I wouldn't "hammer it closed" if it where asked here, though I'd feel it borderline. But I'd not force it open either if the community would VTC it. Waiting for other opinions, I'm afraid …

Comment: Hmmm ... https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13810/fitness-tracking-software-that-doesnt-store-data-online

Comment: Same answer to that question, yes. And that question looks perfectly fine to me, by the way …

Answer (score 1):

Such a question should be asked at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com

On our site is only about software, and you MUST say what hardware you want it to run on.

I would migrate the mistitled [Fitness tracking software that doesn't store data online](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13810/fitness-tracking-software-that-doesnt-store-data-online) (which says `I'd like the device to be [...]`) to hardwarerecs if it was not too old to migrate, and I am in favor of closing it.